# Easy adjustment/alignment of scanned / photographed pages on Linux

Tags: linux, image-processing

Sometimes I need to process scanned images or photographed book covers, where I usually only have the resulting image (JPG/PNG) but not the original (to recreate a clean variant myself). Pages/covers are not always correctly aligned, which is the hardest task of post-processing for me currently: it's a complicated job in Gimp using the "perspective tool", as I've found no alternative to that yet.

Seeing scanning apps on Android, it should be pretty easy to adjust/align such a scanned page:

[image: CamScanner] [image: Mobile Doc Scanner] [image: YouCam]
<sup>Screenshots from [CamScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner) / [Mobile Doc Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stoik.mdscanlite) / [YouCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyberlink.yousnap) (click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, you basically tap the 4 corners of the paper (or rather adjust the "grid" to match them), tap the check-mark in the toolbar (at the bottom), and have the page adjusted.

What's possible on some smartphone with Android shouldn't be too hard to accomplish on a more powerful desktop machine. Nevertheless, either my Google-Fu isn't good enough or there doesn't seem to be a corresponding application.

**Summing up my requirements:**

- must run on Linux (Java applications acceptable, Gimp-addons welcome)
- must be free (as in "free beer" – open-source would be an added plus)
- easy to install (not too many dependencies)
- easy to work with (basically, as easy as it is in mentioned Android apps)
- can be stand-alone or an addon for Gimp

Answer (score 2):

There is a cross platform solution for Windows, OS-X, Linux & Android which uses a combination of:

- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)
- [Python](https://www.python.org/)
- [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) *Windows users will be interested in the [unofficial pre-compiled binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) from Christoph Gohlke*
- [Sci-Kit Image](http://scikit-image.org/) *ditto for windows binaries*
- The python [imutils](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/02/just-open-sourced-personal-imutils-package-series-opencv-convenience-functions/) by Adrian Rosebrock `pip install imutils`

It is:

- Free
- Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Not too many dependencies
- Even easier to work as it doesn't even require you to select the corners it finds them for you providing there is a reasonable contrast in the image.

And it is all spelt out, complete with source code at: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/ by Adrian Rosebrock.

I am not going to reproduce the code here *as there might be copyright issues with doing so* but you are free to use the code which comes to about 70 lines of python from the blog post plus another 30 from a referenced post.

Comment: Thanks, Steve – that'd be something to start with. But I rather was hoping for a ready-to-use solution (not something I need to write myself, as good examples as are provided) – and rather dislike giving them my email address just to download those examples. Also I see I should have been more exact on what "not too many dependencies" is supposed to mean: installing 5 "kits" and then writing my own code is not what I had in mind :) Good find, though – so +1 from me. Hoping for something easier, though :)

Comment: If you had over your email you get the complete program, I just did it.  You do, however, still need to install the dependencies.  I tested it on a small group of images, and if the image contains a square it make lock onto a small potion of the document and only give you that.  It is far from perfect, and only a few minor calibrations can be made.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with the nightly builds of Gimp 2.9 and it features a new perspective transform tool which when applied to one of your samples gives:

[image] -> [image]

So Keep your hopes up - Screenshot of it in action:
[image]

Or ***risk*** the nightly builds!

Comment: Good find, Steve – thanks! That's more like it. Though it means waiting for Gimp 2.10 then (odd numbers are dev builds with Gimp). I wish there was an easy way to install that as "portable" on Linux, so one could use it along the stable version. But I'm not sure if it's the same: That's the tool I'm currently using – and your screenshot doesn't look like one just marks the 4 corners and Gimp transforms that to an rectangle. It rather looks like what I have to do now: manually dragging the corners until it fits?

Comment: @Izzy - It is true that you still have to drag the corners but it is a lot easier to use than the older perspective tools.  If you are prepared to build gimp from source then http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Building/Linux explains how to build and install it without interfering with your existing gimp.

Comment: Thanks, Steve – I might have a look into that – though I'm certain I run into dependency issues concerning "too old libs", still being on Ubuntu 12.04, so I most likely have to postpone that until I found time to setup a new system. So I'll first wait if something more convenient shows up :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Steve. This is cool feature from GNU Gimp. Here goes my work flow. This'll help future readers.

1. `Shift+P` - Open `perspective` tool & adjust the image , their corners
2. `Shift+Ctrl+C` - Copy Visible into memory
3. `Shift+Ctrl+V` - Open new image with transformed image from memory
4. `Shift+Ctrl+E` - Export the final output